# C# Nest Elasticsearch: how to search for multiple parameters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I can search our database using a single search e.g
`.Term("productName", "test")`

We got some scenarios where we got a list of product names to lookup.To avoid a GET request for each product name in the list, I would like to make one GET request containing multiple queries. Problem is that the endpoint doesn't support MultiSearch (_msearch).

My question is, is it possible to do multiple searches using one GET request using the _search endpoint?

The queries are implemented in C# and the Nest framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Term` method you should use `.Query` extension method, like this:

```
.Query(q =>
   q.Terms(p=> p.Key, values)
```

For more info check out the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/writing-queries.html)